# What is the difference between a Class Based View CreateView and the mixing CreateModelMixin

Tags: django-rest-framework, mixins

I am have recently started learning DjangoRestFramework and I came across two ways to create model instances, one is through Django Rest Framework CreateAPIView and the other is CreateModelMixin. So I wanted to know what is the difference between them and also between the other mixins and Views which perform identical functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's the difference: `mixins` are (as described in the code comments) the `basic building blocks for generic class based views` - they're basically view-agnostic python objects, which means you won't be able to use a `CreateModelMixin` alone to actually create a model. You need to inherit that on a new view, and the `CreateAPIView` does exactly that:

```
# Concrete view classes that provide method handlers
# by composing the mixin classes with the base view.

class CreateAPIView(mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                    GenericAPIView):
    """
    Concrete view for creating a model instance.
    """
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

The same concept applies to all other `mixins` and `views` provided, `mixins` are **reusable pieces of code**.

[This](https://spapas.github.io/2018/03/19/comprehensive-django-cbv-guide/) is a great (long, but great) read on that matter, really thorough.

Answer (score 0):

Basically mixins offer a different style multiple inheritance that are used in a lot of programming languages as they provide a better(more flexible) way to deal with method resolution order (MRO) and overriding methods.
Overriding is a common practice in CreateAPIView class but is limited, inheriting and overriding methods from new classes will be next to impossible with CreateAPIView for 2 reasons :

1. as it already has too many classes.
2. they all have their MRO

take a look at these functions at the links bellow things will get clearer

[classy doc of CreateApiView](https://www.cdrf.co/3.13/rest_framework.generics/CreateAPIView.html)

[classy doc CreateModelMixin](https://www.cdrf.co/3.13/rest_framework.mixins/CreateModelMixin.html)